# Select distinct name with random id

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have a table with an id and a name (an a bunch of other stuff not relevant for this query). Now I need an SQL statement that returns one row per distinct name and in that row I need the name and one id (can be any id).

The table is looking something like this:

```
id | name
---+-----
 1 | a2
 2 | a2
 3 | a4
 4 | a4
 5 | a2
 6 | a3
```

btw. using Postgres 8.4

Tried various combinations of grouping or joining with self. Is this even possible without creating extra tables?

Comment: Must the id also be distinct, or can the same id appear multiple times?

Comment: id is primary key, so cant appear multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arbitrarily choosing to return the minimum id per name.

```
SELECT name, MIN(id)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY name
```

Comment: ahh thanks alot , group by was always asking me to group by all attributes i was selecting. didnt know, that this is not the case with funktions on attribs.

Answer (score 0):

You may look at [PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_SELECT_only_the_first_few_rows_of_a_query.3F_A_random_row.3F). It shows how to select random rows.

You may use `random()` function to select random rows using `ORDER BY` clause of `SELECT`. Example:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable ORDER BY random()
```

You can then use `GROUP BY` to select distinct names. You may need to limit results using `LIMIT` clause. So the query looks something like this:

```
SELECT id, name FROM table_name GROUP BY name ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Using a `LIMIT 1` means you'd only get one row returned, not one row per name as OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ID, name from table group by name;
```